# XSLT TO RECUPERATE AN XML FILE INTO MS-ACCESS

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I have a pretty large xml file which I wanna recuperate in ms-access. Here is the structure (in minima of course):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PortfoliosNA>
  <TourOp id="xxx-245-AF">
    <Company>ITS</Company>
    <joined="11-01-2004" />
  </TourOp>
  <TourOp id="xxx-342-EU">
    <Company>TUI</Company>
    <joined="12-03-2004" />
  </TourOp>         
  
  <transfer Local="1001 Nuits Travel" HQ="Cairo" RefTO="xxx-245-AF">
 <Bus>112</Bus>
 <AgentsLoc>17</AgentsLoc>
 <TOleader>4</TOleader>
 <Circuits>Charm-Hurghada</Circuits>
  </transfer>
  <transfer Local="Alpha Tours" HQ="Bratisla." RefTO="xxx-342-EU">
 <Bus>42</Bus>
 <AgentsLoc>4</AgentsLoc>
 <TOleader>2</TOleader>
 <Circuits>xxx</Circuits>
  </transfer>  
 </PortfoliosNA>
```

and I am trying to transform this xml into this:

```
  <PortfoliosNA> 
   <transfer>
     <Local>1001 Nuits Travel</Local>
     <HQ>Cairo</HQ>
     <RefTO>ITS</RefTO> 
     <Bus>112</Bus>
     <AgentsLoc>17</AgentsLoc>
     <TOleader>4</TOleader>
     <Circuits>Charm-Hurghada</Circuits>
   </transfer>
   <transfer>
     <Local>Alpha Tours</Local>
     <HQ>Bratisla.</HQ>
     <RefTO>TUI</RefTO>
     <Bus>42</Bus>
     <AgentsLoc>4</AgentsLoc>
     <TOleader>2</TOleader>
     <Circuits>xxx</Circuits>
   </transfer>
 </PortfoliosNA>
```

As you can see RefTO Node will take the company name value instead of the Id ('ITS' instead of 'xxx-245-AF' for ex.)
So finally I will get a unique table in ms-access called 'transfer' with 7 columns (Local-HQ-RefTO-Bus-Agents-TOLeader-Circuits)

I could have some readable table with an XSLT transforming file but I am still far away from a working table and could absolutely not get the company name as value for 'RefTO' instead of Its ID. 
Here is my XSLT file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
 >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="transfer/@*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Am so grateful for any help to get out of this nightmare and produce my final reports. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="op" match="TourOp" use="@id"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/PortfoliosNA">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="transfer"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="transfer/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="transfer/@RefTO">
    <RefTO>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('op', .)/Company"/>   
    </RefTO>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To understand how this works, read: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html

Comment: OMG like a charm! thank you so so much for saving my life today and thank you for the link. I'll jump there for to better understand the mechanism and face the next similar needs. Xml is not really my 'happiness' but I have to.